# Seaborn/Plotly multiple y-axes

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, seaborn

I would like to get a plot with more than two different y-axes in seaborn using a pandas dataframe similar to this example for matlotlib: https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html

As it will be used in a function I want to be flexible in selecting how many and which column of a Pandas dataframe will be ploted.

Unfortunately Seaborn seems to only move the last added scale.
Here is what I want to do with a Seaborn sample dataset:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=sns.load_dataset("mpg")
df=df.loc[df['model_year']<78]

show=['mpg','displacement','acceleration']

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
sns.scatterplot('weight',show[0],data=df.reset_index(),style='model_year') 
del show[0]
k=1
off=0
for i in show:
    a = plt.twinx()
    a=sns.scatterplot('weight',i,data=df.reset_index(),ax=a, color=list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS)[k],legend=False,style='model_year')
    a.spines['right'].set_position(('outward', off))
    a.yaxis.label.set_color(list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS)[k])
    k+=1
    off+=60
```

[image]

I want to create a function with the possibility to flexible plot different columns. Up to now this seems to be quite complicated in plotly to me (no way of just do a loop). I would also go with plotly, if there is a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now implemented this using plotly.

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df=sns.load_dataset("mpg")

show=['mpg','displacement','acceleration']

mcolors=[
    '#1f77b4',  # muted blue
    '#ff7f0e',  # safety orange
    '#2ca02c',  # cooked asparagus green
    '#d62728',  # brick red
    '#9467bd',  # muted purple
    '#8c564b',  # chestnut brown
    '#e377c2',  # raspberry yogurt pink
    '#7f7f7f',  # middle gray
    '#bcbd22',  # curry yellow-green
    '#17becf'   # blue-teal
];


fig = go.Figure()
m=0
for k in df.model_year.unique():
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x = df.loc[df.model_year == k]['weight'],
        y = df.loc[df.model_year == k][show[0]],
        name = str(k), 
        mode = 'markers',
        marker_symbol=m,
        marker_line_width=0,
        marker_size=6,
        marker_color=mcolors[0],
    ))
    m+=1

layout = {'xaxis':dict(
        domain=[0,0.7]
        ),
          'yaxis':dict(
            title=show[0],
            titlefont=dict(
                color=mcolors[0]
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color=mcolors[0]
        ),
          showgrid=False
          )}
n=2
for i in show[1::]:
    m=0
    for k in df.model_year.unique():
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x = df.loc[df.model_year == k]['weight'],
            y = df.loc[df.model_year == k][i],
            name = str(k), 
            yaxis ='y'+str(n),
            mode = 'markers',
            marker_symbol=m,
            marker_line_width=0,
            marker_size=6,
            marker_color=mcolors[n],
            showlegend = False
        ))
        m+=1

    layout['yaxis'+str(n)] = dict(
        title=i,
        titlefont=dict(
            color=mcolors[n]
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color=mcolors[n]
            ),
        anchor="free",
        overlaying="y",
        side="right",
        position=(n)*0.08+0.55,
        showgrid=False,
    )
    n+=1

fig.update_layout(**layout)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a good way in Plotly, you can see the code example for the picture below, similar to your matplotlib example in [this section of the docs](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes).

[image: final result]

Comment: As far as I understand it, adding traces to the Plotly figure is not as elegant and simple as using Plotly Express or Seaborn in terms of handling a pandas dataframe. Things like defining the marker style by the values of a column make it even more complex. It is a pity to lose all the utility for this particular problem.

Comment: I'd say that depends on how you use it. The imperative alternative described in [here](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-plotly-py-3-0-0-7bb1333f69c6) makes a lot of sense to me in terms of elegance, it may be more code than Express but the features are worth it and at the end of the day is much much easier to make changes.